# Where to use Binary SSL Transport on port and Thrift SSL port of worker in wso2 api manager 3.2.0

Tags: wso2-api-manager

In wso2 api manager when I run worker, there are some enabled ports as following :

```
 - Started Binary SSL Transport on port : 9712
 - Started Binary TCP Transport on port : 9612
 - Service Component is activated
 - Thrift Server started at 0.0.0.0
 - Thrift SSL port : 7712
 - Thrift port : 7612
```

Where I should use in deployment.toml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the data receiver configurations under `dataReceivers` of the `databridge.config` section of the `<ANALYTICS_HOME>/conf/worker/deployment.yaml` file.

```
    # Data receiver configurations
    # THIS IS A MANDATORY FIELD
  dataReceivers:
  -
      # Data receiver configuration
    dataReceiver:
        # Data receiver type
        # THIS IS A MANDATORY FIELD
      type: Thrift
        # Data receiver properties
      properties:
        tcpPort: '7611'
        sslPort: '7711'

  -
      # Data receiver configuration
    dataReceiver:
        # Data receiver type
        # THIS IS A MANDATORY FIELD
      type: Binary
        # Data receiver properties
      properties:
        tcpPort: '9611'
        sslPort: '9711'
        tcpReceiverThreadPoolSize: '100'
        sslReceiverThreadPoolSize: '100'
        hostName: 0.0.0.0
```

In the server logs, the ports are printed with an offset of 1. This is because, if you look at the top of the deployment.yaml file, it can be seen that the port offset is set to 1.